# Android Viewbinding with *multiple* <merge> possible?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewbinding

I have a layout like this

**MainLayout.xml**

```
<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnCount="3">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/filter_group_air_date"
        layout="@layout/layout_filter_dropdown_with_lt_gt_buttons" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/filter_group_vote_avg"
        layout="@layout/layout_filter_dropdown_with_lt_gt_buttons" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/filter_group_min_votes"
        layout="@layout/layout_filter_dropdown_with_lt_gt_buttons" />

</GridLayout>
```

And here's the included layout file

**layout_filter_dropdown_with_lt_gt_buttons.xml**

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Placeholder"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal|center_vertical" />

</merge>
```

Upon launch the app crashes with

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Missing required view with ID: org.package:id/filter_group_air_date
```

It's because of assigning an id to the  elements.

I see the solution is to remove the ID assignment on the  elements, and to bind the  layout in the onCreateView() function, etc. Then use that binding in your code to access the element.

But, what if there are multiple instances, as above? How do I differentiate between them without an ID?

Comment: For now I've abandoned <merge>, turned them into root LinearLayout, and got rid of the parent container GridLayout and mimicked the grid cells via LinearLayout stuff